# Do there always exist invertible elements in unital ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a unital ring, not necessarily commutative. Is there some way to prove that any such ring always has invertible elements other than $1$? That is, some way to force $ab=1$ for some $a,b \neq 1$, apart from the case $R = \{0,1\}$ ?

Comment: $\Bbb F_2\times \Bbb F_2$ only has $1$. However, as soon as $1+1\ne 0$ there's at least $-1$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why this is true?

Comment: Because $1\ne-1$ and $(-1)(-1)=1$?

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you meant there's at least 1, I didn't see the minus sign. Thanks!

Comment: To the question asked: “no. Boolean rings (with identity) have exactly one invertible element.”